# The IPSec connection has been successfully established. I can only ping the remote endpoint, but cannot ping the entire subnet

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

server A:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciery.png)

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes 
conn home-to-aliyun
     ikelifetime=36000s
        keylife=8h
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=5
    #    mobike=no
        lifetime=8h
        left=192.168.20.6
        leftid=221.220.135.110
        leftsubnet=192.168.20.0/24
        right=182.92.125.208
        rightsubnet=172.16.73.190/20
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp2048
        esp=aes256-sha2_256
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=start
        type=tunnel
```

server B:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jcpT.png)

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    #charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2"
    uniqueids=yes 
conn aliyun-to-home
        ikelifetime=36000s
        keylife=8h
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=5
#       mobike=no
        lifetime=8h
        left=172.16.73.190
        leftid=182.92.125.208
        leftsubnet=172.16.73.0/24
        right=221.220.135.110
        rightsubnet=192.168.20.190/20
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp2048
        esp=aes256-sha2_256
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=start
        type=tunnel
```

cannot ping the entire subnet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn3u4.png)

Comment: All of that and no routing tables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.